# Unable to call API of slim framework

Tags: php, api, slim

I am designing an API in PHP using slim framework. These are working fine on my local system and my public IP. But now I upload these APIs files on to my company server.

Now I am trying to access API stored on my company's server but these are showing empty pages, this means I am unable to call API.

Here is the API

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Include the Slim library
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

// Instantiate the Slim class
$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Pericent is working on Campus Concierge...";
});

$app->run();

?>
```

This is working correctly locally, but it is not showing anything when I want to access company server.

Comment: Turn on error reporting on the live server so you can see what is going on. Is the server running PHP 5.3?

Comment: Sir i dont know how can we turn on error reporting on server.

Comment: SIr now its PHP 5.2 But still it is not working. Please help me sir, give more suggestions. I really need help.

Comment: In my answer I also stated: `Also note that as you are using a closure in your code above you will need at least PHP 5.3 to proceed.`

Comment: Okay Treffynnon sir. Thank you so much. Now i ask Seniors to update PHP. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommend **PHP >= 5.3** to enjoy Slim's support for anonymous functions like as **Get,Post,put and delete**.

So if we want to make APIs using SLIM framework we need to update our PHP>=5.3. Then your APIs like as Get and Post will work successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your live server to support PHP 5.1, which is the minimum requirement for [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/):

> - Web server (URL rewrite module recommended)
> - PHP >= 5.1
> - libmcrypt > 2.4.x (if using encrypted cookies)

Also note that as you are using a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in your code above you will need at least PHP 5.3 to proceed.

The version your server is running is [nearly **12 years old**](http://php.net/releases/index.php#4.0.1) and it is not even the last PHP4 release!!

The manual states that:

> Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31.