# Error in SLIM framework

Tags: php, api, slim

I have created APIs using SLIM framework. These APIs are running correct when i run these APIs in PHP 5.3  But when i run these on a system which has PHP 5.2 then these do not work.

These is a file named .htaccess which is creating problem in PHP 5.2.

This following is code of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#


# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Please tell me what should i do to run my APIs in PHP 5.2 also

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278813/unable-to-call-api-of-slim-framwork I don't see how this .htaccess file is causing an error in PHP. Does your live server allow .htaccess files (`AllowOverride`)?

Comment: Yes sir this almost same to my previous question but it is more closure to my problem thats why i post this also. If you feel this is duplicate then you can delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure it's the .htaccess file that is the problem?

It sounds to me like its a PHP problem as you say it doesn't work when using a lower version.

Slim uses anonymous functions a lot in it's examples, if your using them in your application then they won't be supported in PHP < 5.3.

http://www.slimframework.com/read/hello-world

**Edit**

Judging from your previous question and sample code, this is the actual case.

Comment: Thank you fire... you are right. We cant use function format like as get and post if we have PHP<5.3. I updated PHP to 5.3. Now its working fine.